# How to parse string in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am calculating the columns total however at some cases i have to input char/string. how could i parse these data types in datagridview. here is my code:

```
dim stdntscore,ttlscore as decimal

If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then

     For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

                    stdntscore += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)
                    ttlscore +=Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value)

Next

end if
```

mycode calculates decimal but it says an error when i input string

Answer (score 0):

TryParse will assign a value if it can understand the value.  It returns true if it could decipher it, and false if it couldn't.  If you want to add the number if it's a decimal and ignore it if it is not a valid decimal,

```
dim stdntscore,ttlscore as decimal

If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then

   For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                Dim score as Decimal
                If Decimal.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value, score)
                    stdntscore += score
                    ttlscore += score
                ' Else
                    ' Ignore - not a number
                End If

Next

end if
```